# Find all files that are filled with zeros

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have roughly 30 GB of text files that have 6 lines of header and then content that can be best imagined as a matrix, from tiny 1x1 to having tens of thousands of rows and columns. Numbers in the content can take only two values: 0 and 1.

I would like to find all files that have content filled with zeros, so not a single '1' value. Writing a script in, say, Python should be straightforward, but I would like to learn how to this in e.g. awk, grep or sed.

One way I can think of is just to use grep to search for '1' and if it is not found in the given file then we have a match (since we have only two possible values) - but how can I search from a specific line, i.e. skip header?

Comment: `tail -n +10` would give you lines 11+ from the file, which you could then grep.

Comment: `sed -n '2,${/1/;p;}' file` Starts at 2nd line and scans to end-of-file `$`, if 1 is found, the line is printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F'1' '
FNR>6 && NF>1 { f=1; nextfile }
ENDFILE { print FILENAME, (f ? "got a one" : "all zeros"); f=0 }
' file1 file2 ...
```

The above uses GNU awk for ENDFILE and nextfile.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose I have the two files:

```
$ cat 1_1.txt
Header 1
Header 2
Header 3
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
$ cat zereos.txt
Header 1
Header 2
Header 3
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

You can use sed to skip over N lines of the header and print then any lines with a `1` in them:

```
$ sed -n '1,3d; /1/p' zereos.txt 
$ sed -n '1,3d; /1/p' 1_1.txt 
0 0 0 1 0
```

So now combine that into a Bash script:

```
for file in *
   do rtr=$(sed -n '1,3d; /1/p' "$file")
   if [[ $rtr =~ ^$ ]]; then echo "$file" 
   fi
done
```

Prints

```
zereos.txt
```

Comment: Works well! Only reason I am not selecting this answer is just that the other one is much faster.

Answer (score 1):

My take:

```
for file in *; do
    if sed 1,6d "$file" | grep -q 1; then
        echo "$file has a one"
    else
        echo "$file has no ones"
    fi
done
```

With GNU sed, you can write

```
for file in *; do
    if sed -n '1,6d; /1/ q 1' "$file"; then
        echo "$file has no ones"
    else
        echo "$file has a one"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Very nice and clear answer; also works as expected! Only reason I did not select this one is just the other one was slightly faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The next script will count the total number of `1` in the given file, e.g. not only the number of lines what contains some `1` but the real number of `1` in all lines and all columns:

```
file="somefile.txt"
tail +7 "$file" | grep -o 1 | grep -c '.'
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^
       |              |            +--- count the number of lines
       |              +---- filter out all "1" - each on alone line
       +-------- prints the file from the 7th line
```

you can use it like

```
file="somefile"
ones=$(tail +6 "$file" | grep -o 1 | grep -c '.')
case "$ones" in
    0) do_something "$file" ;;       #no 1 in the file
    *) do_other "$file" "$ones" ;;   #here is $ones number of "1"
esac
```

you can count the 1 with perl also

```
perl -nlE '$.<7&&next;$c+=()=m/1/g}{say $c' < filename
```

e.g

```
ones=$(perl -nlE '$.<7&&next;$c+=()=m/1/g}{say $c' < filename)
```

Comment: Why not just: tail +7 "$file" | grep -c 1

Comment: @AlainCollins because the `grep -c 1` prints only the count of lines what contains any `1` e.g. the line with a content `1 0 1 1 1` will be counted only 1x. e.g. you will get the number of lines containing 1 and nie the total count of 1 in all lines and all columns... `echo '1 0 0 1 1' | grep -c 1` prints `1`, while `echo '1 0 0 1 1' | grep -o 1 | grep -c ''` prints `3`.

Comment: I didn't see "how many 1's on a row" in the OP's request.  Cool, though.

Comment: Maybe it is just my version of tail (?), but the following will not work: tail +7; option '-n' is mandatory. Counting is not necessary or even not advised due to the size of files. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for something like this:

```
gawk '
  BEGINFILE { no_ones = 1 };
  NR < 7 { next };
  /1/ { no_ones = 0; nextfile };
  ENDFILE { if (no_ones) print FILENAME }
' files...
```

This uses GNU awk (for BEGINFILE, ENDFILE, nextfile).